# How to pass data into view file

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

My core class

```
class MY_Loader extends CI_Loader
{
    public function template($template_name, $vars = array(), $return = FALSE)
    {
        if($return):
            $content  = $this->view('admin/common/header', $vars, $return);
            $content  = $this->view('admin/common/leftmenu', $vars, $return);
            $content  = $this->view('admin/common/topbar', $vars, $return);
            $content .= $this->view($template_name, $vars, $return);
            $content .= $this->view('admin/common/footer', $vars, $return);
            return $content;
        else:
            $this->view('admin/common/header', $vars);
            $this->view('admin/common/leftmenu', $vars);
            $this->view('admin/common/topbar', $vars);
            $this->view($template_name, $vars);
            $this->view('admin/common/footer', $vars);
        endif;
    }
}
```

My function

```
public function index()
{
    $title = "Hello Admin";
    $this->load->template('admin/cmspages', $title);
}

<div class="container-fluid">
      <!-- Page Heading -->
      <h1 class="h3 mb-4 text-gray-800">Blank Page </h1>
      <?php echo $title ; ?>
</div>
```

i made common header footer and sidebar using ci_loader in core folder but unable to paas value in view page what i have to do?

i have tried these code please explain where i am wrong

Comment: What do you get on the page? Error? Also, $vars will need to have all values as desired by other header,leftbar... templates as well.

Comment: @ajay Kumar: Please show view page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `template` method (and CI `view` method) awaits `$vars` as array, but you are passing only string.

Correct usage would be:

```
public function index() {
    $data = array(
        'title' => 'Hello Admin',
    );
    $this->load->template('admin/cmspages', $data);
}
```